# user authentification failure despite successful login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

The below login solution is not successfully authenticating the user.

After the `login_user(user)` function is called, the current_user is supposed to be authenticated.
When trying: `print(flask_login.current_user.is_authenticated)` immediately after login this returns **TRUE**, but as soon as the next page loads it returns **FALSE**.
In summary: **The user authentification state is not persistent.**

Consequently, pages protected with the `@flask_login.login_required` decorator (below the `@app.route` line) are inaccessible and I am redirected to the `@login_manager.unauthorized_handler` page.

As I understand it, the Flask framework is supposed to set cookies or send some kind of information in the headers that contain some kind of authentication. I also tried using the flask 'sessions' module and also tried using the 'g' module, but these produced entirely different errors.

The below version of the code I plagiarised from https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login, which uses only the things I have below. Yet for some reason, my version isn't working.

For the purposes of this testing phase, I made a list containing python dicts of a user so I don't have to make multiple unnecessary calls to the Firebase db I'm using to store the info.

This is the setup section for the login manager including my copy of the UserMixin class:

```
app.secret_key = 'dummysecretkey'
login_manager = flask_login.LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

class User(flask_login.UserMixin):
    pass
```

This is a sample of the structure of the users:

```
    {
    'email': 'email@domain.com',
    'password': 'password',
    'username': 'user01'
    ...*other fields*...
    }
```

Here are the routes for the login manager:

```
    @login_manager.user_loader
    def user_loader(username):
        for entries in users:
            if entries['username'] not in users:
                return

        for entries in users:
            if entries['username'] == username:

                user = User()
                user.id = entries['username']
                return user

    @login_manager.request_loader
    def request_loader(request):
        username = request.form.get('username')

        try:
            for entries in users:
                if entries['username'] == username:
                    user = User()
                    user.id = entries['username']
                    user.is_authenticated = request.form['password'] == entries['password']
            return user
        except:
            return None

    @app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login():
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return render_template('login.html')

        uname = request.form['uname']
        psw = request.form['psw']
        for entries in users:
            if uname == entries['username'] and psw == entries['password']:
                user = User()
                user.id = uname
                flask_login.login_user(user)
                print(flask_login.current_user.is_authenticated)
                return redirect(url_for('addnew'))

        return 'Bad login'
```

Example route that requires authentication:

```
    @app.route('/addnew')
    @flask_login.login_required
    def addnew():
        return render_template("addnew.html")
```

Notwithstanding the flaws in the password comparison (I'm aware they're insecure), could someone please point out the flaw in the above code or present an alternative to achieve the login authentication?

Comment: I have no time to check your code, but fwiw I use Flask Login for several projects and it works like a charm. Maybe I have a chance to have a look at your code later.

Answer (score 0):

I am bit confused by your code.

From the Flask Login documentation:

> Sometimes you want to login users without using cookies, such as using header values or an api key passed as a query argument. In these cases, you should use the request_loader callback.

But I understand you want to use cookie based login?

So you should not use the `request_loader`.

Also, why do you instantiate a new `User` in the login route? The login should compare the login data with already existing users.

I suggest you "manually" instantiate the users and put them in a list like this:

```
users = []
a = User()
a.name = "name_a"
a.id = "id_a"
users.append(a)
...
```

And then adapt your user_loader to compare the login data from the form with the existing data.

There is an excellent Flask tutorial out there by Miguel Grinberg, which also explains the user login:

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Comment: Thanks so much for this. You make a valid point. The tutorial you referenced is one of the many I reviewed in an attempt to solve this issue. I struggled with his method because I'm using firebase for my db instead of an SQL database, so the class instantiation proved problematic as I couldn't get the load_user() function to gel with my User class. It constantly gave me this error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'user_id'". I shall give it another try though. Thanks once again for taking the time to look at this. I appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'd appreciate an upvote for my answer. Fingers crossed you figure out the rest of your problem. Unfortunately I am not familiar with Firebase, but it should be possible in some way to retrieve data from it :-)

Comment: I feel like an enormous idiot. It has taken me two days to understand that I was implemented the load_user function completely incorrectly. I thought it's supposed to return the user_id of the user class. Turns out it's supposed to be a sort of search function that returns the entire user instance when passed the user id as an argument. I'm still in disbelief that it's working now. Thanks again.

Comment: also: "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." So my vote doesn't count sorry.